# TextField rejected resignFirstResponder when being removed from hierarchy

Tags: swift, uitextfield, first-responder, inputaccessoryview

I'm trying to make a custom textfield/sendbutton view that overrides `inputAccessoryView`, but I'm having 2 problems I can't seem to solve:

When the custom view becomes the first responder, I get this warning twice:

```
CustomKeyboardProject[5958:3107074] API error: 
<_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x119e2bd70; frame = (0 0; 0 0); 
layer = <CALayer: 0x283df9e00>> returned 0 width, 
assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
```

Then when I try to resign the custom view as the first responder, Xcode throws this warning:

```
CustomKeyboardProject[5958:3107074] -[UIWindow
endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on <UITextEffectsWindow:
0x11a055400; frame = (0 0; 375 667); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer =
<UIWindowLayer: 0x283df78a0>> without matching 
-beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring.
```

Has anyone been able to silence these warnings?

Heres my code:

```
protocol CustomTextFieldDelegate: class {
    func sendMessage()
}

class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var canResignFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
}

class CustomKeyboardView: UIView {

    let textField: CustomTextField = {
        let textField = CustomTextField()
        textField.backgroundColor = .green
        textField.textColor = .white
        return textField
    }()

    let attachButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.setTitle("Attach", for: .normal)
        return button
    }()

    let sendButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        button.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendMessage), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    @objc func sendMessage() {
        delegate?.sendMessage()
    }

    weak var delegate: CustomTextFieldDelegate?

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        setViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setViews() {
        let subviews = [attachButton, sendButton, textField]

        subviews.forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview($0)
        }

        autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight

        subviews.forEach {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                $0.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
                ])
        }

        layoutSubviews()

        [attachButton, sendButton].forEach {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: $0.heightAnchor),
                $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.heightAnchor)
                ])
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            attachButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
            textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: attachButton.trailingAnchor),
            sendButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.trailingAnchor),
            sendButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            ])
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return .zero
    }
}

class CustomTableView: UITableView {

    let keyboardView = CustomKeyboardView()

    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableView.Style) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
        keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var canResignFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return keyboardView
    }
}

private let reuseId = "MessageCellId"

class ExampleViewController: UITableViewController {

    private let customTableView = CustomTableView()

    var messages = [String]()

    override func loadView() {
        tableView = customTableView
        view = tableView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.becomeFirstResponder()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        customTableView.keyboardView.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.customTableView.keyboardView.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    // tableView delegate methods

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messages.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseId)
        cell?.textLabel?.text = messages[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }

    override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        customTableView.keyboardView.textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}

extension ExampleViewController: CustomTextFieldDelegate {
    func sendMessage() {
        // double check something is in textField
        let textField = customTableView.keyboardView.textField
        guard let body = textField.text, body != "" else { return }
        messages.append(body)
        tableView.reloadData()

        view.endEditing(true)
        customTableView.keyboardView.textField.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: first thing, try to design the inputAccessoryView in a Xib, it will show you any constraint error you might have. Second, I would recomment to have the custom inputAccessoryView top view to be attached to superview (to cover the whole inputAccessoryView area. Then, make a new subview containing all items (buttons, input, button) and force a minimum height to this container view. Finally, attach this subview to the SafeArea sides and you can do a top Space to superview >= SafeArea.top. The only thing you need there is the intrinsicContentSize -> zero that you already have.

Comment: I get the same error that you have about UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated. but I don't find anything to fix this. I also get another error when I do interactive close keyboard: " First responder warning ... rejected resignFirstResponder when being removed from hierarchy" in my case

Comment: But I don't have : CustomKeyboardProject[5958:3107074] API error: 
<_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x119e2bd70; frame = (0 0; 0 0); 
layer = <CALayer: 0x283df9e00>> returned 0 width, 
assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric

Comment: @Mikael thanks for taking a look! I like the idea of creating a new view to add to the superview, but I was looking to override the inputAccessoryView because I want to be able to drag the view down with a swipe (in conjunction with the `.interactive` keyboard dismissing.) and I'm not sure that would be smooth with a separate view on top of the inputAccessoryView area (unless I'm understanding you incorrectly?)

Comment: I sometimes receive that `endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated` error sometimes, but I'm unable to recreate it. Do you know when it shows up for you?

Comment: "I like the idea of creating a new view to add to the superview" I was talking about the inputAccessoryView subviews composition (not superview). It means that you will use inputAccessoryView in my proposal as well.

Comment: I need more time to investigate this issue, I ll come back here in a few days - have to finish other tasks before then -

Comment: not much found yet. for the rotation warning, a guy found this interesting behavior: https://www.codesd.com/item/a-uiwindow-enddisablinginterfaceautorotationanimated-error-appears-in-the-console-when-the-keyboard-is-interactively-disabled-from-collectionview-in-ios9-only.html .  Regarding the resign problem, by stopping the UITextField to resign with a canResignFirstResponder { return false } in the UITextField subclass, the warning doesn't appear anymore after the interactive keyboard dismissal.

Comment: @Mikael Wouldn't overriding that property to be false just keep the textField as the firstResponder the entire time? I just read this and if you call `.removeFromSuperView()` on the customInputView on `viewWillDisappear()` the `rejected resignFirstResponder` error goes away

Comment: The warning appears when you dismiss the keyboard with an interactive swipe down on the tableView. Therefore, viewWillDisappear is not called.

Comment: Wilson, yes, the override lock the firstResponder within the textfield. It's only a test and the test shows that if you block it, the warning doesn't appear. I tried it because we get the warning saying that it rejected TextField rejected resignFirstResponder when being removed from hierarchy but in the end, the textfield is not firstResponder anymore after the interactive keyboard dismiss is done.

Comment: @Mikael my bad, I meant that the error doesn’t appear when you transition from the view. You’re right it still appears when the keyboard is dismissed otherwise.